# How can I tell what time it is in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How do you tell time on Pokemon Y?  I have tried the main menu.

Comment: Pretty sure there is something like a "clock app" on the lower screen that you can get. Try the screens down there. Also you can hit the home button and you can check the time without closing your game.

Comment: @Dupree3: You're thinking of DPPt.  Other versions don't have "clock apps."

Comment: The time on Pokémon Y is equal to the time set on your Nintendo 3DS. If you want to change the time you must change the time of your 3DS. This is only possible every 24 hrs.

Comment: There's one 'way' you can guess the time, it's by looking at your player's shadow if you're outside and there's sun. The shadow's length and position changes and the time goes by. Of course, now that won't work during the night :)

Answer (score 5):

Just press home. That will take you back to the main 3DS menu, and there's a clock in the upper-right corner of the top screen. There's no in-game way to see the time, but the in-game time is identical to the time on your 3DS.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there *is* sort of a way to tell the time in game. Just press save and it will bring up the save screen, along with a time stamp. This time stamp corresponds to your 3DS time stamp (although, in 24 hour format I think).

Then cancel the save, and continue becoming a pokemon master!

Comment: As an emulator user, this is exactly the answer I needed. And it let me know I needed to adjust settings to get in sync with real world time where I live.

Answer (score -2):

You can find it in the Trainer Information page.

Comment: That may be true, but it'd be more helpful to the OP if you could also summarise what is said there.